# Is the difference between "what a nerve" and "what nerve" regional?

Tags: british-english

I understand "what (a) nerve!" means "how rude".

I somehow always thought "what a nerve" is more common and was surprised at the exchange made in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97806/45489). Apparently American English speakers feel "what a nerve" is strange.

My questions:

- Is it correct to think that the difference is regional? More specifically US/UK?
- If there are native speakers from other countries, how do you feel about "what a nerve"?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147021/discussion-on-question-by-sundowner-is-the-difference-between-what-a-nerve-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.